# combobox que entregue ciertos datos

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Tengo en mente un form de windows en visual studio el cual estoy colocando un combobox el cual me muestra las "ubicaciones" pero en la base de datos access tengo ubicacion y estado"Activa o Inactiva", la pregunta es puedo hacer que el combobox solo tome las ubicaiones que estan activa y no me muestre ambas?

mi form tiene este codigo

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: esta línea de código carga datos en la tabla 'InventarioDataSet.Ubicaciones' Puede moverla o quitarla según sea necesario.
    Me.UbicacionesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InventarioDataSet.Ubicaciones)

End Sub

Private Sub UbicacionesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UbicacionesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.UbicacionesBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.InventarioDataSet)

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Gustavo, bienvenido a SO en español, edita tu pregunta poniendo el codigo que tienes hasta el momento para poder ayudarte mejor.En tu consulta a access puedes filtrar por estados asi, el resultado sera la lista de ubicaciones con estado "activo"

Comment: Estimado, bienvenido y como dijo @Capt.Teach te invito a que visites este link para informarte [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cuando tengas mas o menos clara la pregunta te ayudaremos !

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de Linq para filtrar tu lista. En esta caso en específico un where puede ayudar.

Algo así como:

```
List<TuClase> listaUbicacionesActivas = ubicaciones.Where(u => u.Activa == true);
```

Lo que quiero hacer notar es la parte del Linq y su diferentes opciones. Pudieras investigar más sobre el tema en muchos tutoríales. Como este https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/linq_overview.htm